# Get highest point of interval in Grafana

Tags: prometheus, grafana, aggregation

I am using Grafana Prometheus. My input data looks like the following:

[image: Grafana Panel]

The tests are triggered at random times and the duration can vary. I am only interessted in the maximum of each interval in which a test is triggered (the red crosses).

In Grafana Cloud, there is a method of [vertical aggregation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana-cloud/data-configuration/metrics/metrics-graphite/aggregation/) where the aggregate() and maxSeries() functions reduce each interval to a single maximum point. Is there something similar in Grafana?

max_over_time(range-vector) might work, but if I use a specific interval and there are multiple test results in that interval, only one result is displayed and the other test results with lower maximum scores are hidden. I want the maximum score for each test run.

Comment: Is it possible that two tests are triggered in a row, or is some time (like 1 minute) between two tests mandatory (or at least safe to assume)?